# How to create a plug-in registry using CMake?

Tags: cmake

My modular C++ application consists of several modules, each plugging in at link time via a public service provider interface. The interface (C++ pure virtual class) and the implementing modules (deriving from the pure virtual class) are modeled as individual CMake targets. Which modules are included in a particular build depends on the configuration.

Now, I want to create a registry listing all implementations for a given service provider interface available in the particular configuration (to eventually generate code allowing instantiation of modules and iterating over them).

Is there a CMake mechanism, which allows to attach additional information with a target (e.g. the implementation class name) and later aggregate this information from all active dependencies of the top target listed by target_link_libraries()?

Comment: You can create a custom property with `define_property` and then `set_target_property`. The worst part is "later affrefate this information" - I don't know if custom properties are inherited, I think not, so you would have to iterate over all dependencies of a target and aggregate the information yourself.